# How can I protect a house foundation from weather conditions?

Tags: foundation, waterproofing

I started building a house and had to divert my money into another situation which was urgent. It might take some time to retrieve the money so the building is on hold.

Only the house foundation is built. It a reinforce concrete slab.I'm in a temperate to continental weather zone, Central and Southeastern Europe. This means 4 seasons, hot in summer (mostly > 35 degrees Celsius), cold in winter (mostly < 10 degrees Celsius), spring and autumn with moderate amount of precipitation. Don't know how long it's possible to suspend the project, 1 maybe 2 years tops.

How can I best protect it from rain, frost, heat etc. until I can return to it?

Comment: If your foundation is damaged by rain, frost, or heat, it's not a very good foundation. Is the foundation built for a basement (below grade) and how is the drainage around the foundation?

Comment: Is the foundation laid out, or is it built? What is it made of? What is your climate? How long will you be gone?

Comment: @BMitch: it is a concrete slab foundation. The ground is slightly tilted around the perimeter.

Comment: @Jay Bazuzi: It's made of reinforced concrete. I'm in a  temperate to continental whether, Central and Southeastern Europe. This means 4 seasons, hot in summer (mostly > 35 degrees Celsius), cold in winter (mostly < 10 degrees Celsius), spring and autumn with moderate amount of precipitation. Don't know how long it's possible to suspend the project, 1 maybe 2 years tops I hope

Comment: I like this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concrete itself should be fine. Make sure water doesn't have anywhere it can pool, since standing water, concrete, and freezing temperatures can lead to cracking. I would protect any metal brackets or bolts intended to secure the framing to the foundation. And I would also protect any plumbing coming through the foundation. Where the water line is exposed, make sure it's drained, cap the end, and cover it in pipe insulation and then some plastic. Throw out some grass seed around the yard to minimize erosion.